# c -switch "unknown" case

Tags: c, keyword

I did recently read a bit of the st terminal sourcecode. There I did find this piece of code:

```
switch (csiescseq.mode[0]) {
default:
unknown:
    fprintf(stderr, "erresc: unknown csi ");
    csidump();
    /* die(""); */
    break;
case '@': /* ICH -- Insert <n> blank char */
```

What does the "unknown" keyword(?) do? I wasn't able to find anything to a "unknown" keyword anywhere.
Thanks in advice for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this code, `unknown` is simply a label. C permits you to prefix any statement with a label. The label can be used as the target of a `goto` statement.

This is in the grammar in C 2018 6.8.1, “Labeled statements”:

> *labeled-statement*:
>     *identifier* : *statement*
>     **case** *constant-expression* : *statement*
>     **default** : *statement*
>
> …
>
> Any statement may be preceded by a prefix that declares an identifier as a label name.